# Numpy Array: Extract Array Row (i) and Column (j) from Index x[i][j]

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy

This seems like a pipe dream if it exists, but I figured I would ask just in case...

Long story short, I'm trying to pull in an element of an array and do multiple manipulations on it. I'm trying to use a class to organize the manipulations.

However, when feeding an element from an array, I need the value of the row and column as well. To reduce the number of inputs that I have to feed into the class function, I was hoping there was a way I could extract the characteristics of the array element I was passing in (even though I know that's not what the function "sees"...). Obviously doable without, but was thinking if I didn't have to pass in redundant (sort of?) information, it might look cleaner so hoped the experts might have a way...Thanks!

#### Example element value would be the value from A[0][1]

```
class Element():
    def __init__(self, element, row, col): 
        self.element = element
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
```

#### What I was hoping exists somewhere...

```
class Element():
    def __init__(self, element): 
        self.element = element
        numpy.row(element) = row    #or some other package?
        numpy.col(element) = col
```

Comment: `np.where(A == element)`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're asking for doesn't exist. After you index array to get a value, the value doesn't have any association with the array any more. To find its index again, you'd need to search the array (which may be slow if it's large). I'd suggest going the other direction. Instead of storing the element in your class, store the indexes (nd a reference to the array, and look up the value when you need it.

Comment: Good call - thanks all.